# cpuminer: Running two nodes -The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error, json_rpc_call failed, retry after 30 seconds

Tags: bitcoind, miner-configuration, testnet, cpuminer

I'm trying to mine new blocks using cpuminer. My blockchain network runs on localhost on the testnet network with two nodes. When I'm trying to mine the blocks I'm receiving the following error:

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
[2020-08-19 10:46:01] Binding thread 6 to cpu 6
[2020-08-19 10:46:01] Binding thread 4 to cpu 4
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 18001 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'liork'
[2020-08-19 10:46:01] Binding thread 2 to cpu 2
> POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:18001
Authorization: Basic bGlvcms6aXJvY2s=
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: cpuminer/2.5.1
X-Mining-Extensions: midstate
Content-Length: 147

* upload completely sent off: 147 out of 147 bytes
[2020-08-19 10:46:01] Binding thread 0 to cpu 0
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
* The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
* Closing connection 0
[2020-08-19 10:46:01] HTTP request failed: The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
[2020-08-19 10:46:01] json_rpc_call failed, retry after 30 seconds
```

My nodes configuration:

Node1:

```
...
# Options only for testnet
[test]
connect=127.0.0.1:17002
rpcport=18001
listen=1
port=17001
rpcuser=myuser
rpcpassword=mypassword
...
```

Node2:

```
...
# Options only for testnet
[test]
connect=127.0.0.1:17001
rpcport=18002
listen=1
port=17002
rpcuser=myuser
rpcpassword=mypassword
...
```

I'm running the cpuminer using the command: `./minerd --url=http://127.0.0.1:18001 --user=myuser --pass=mypassword --coinbase-addr=my_address --protocol-dump`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because new blocks are not generated few days, I got this error.
To solve this I generate a new block using the bitcoin cli:

`./bitcoin-cli --datadir=<dir_to_wallet> generatetoaddress 1 <wallet_address>`